# Transitive relations in R: finding all linked records of a value

Tags: r, match, relationship, igraph

I have a data frame that shows linked records:

```
df <- data.frame(case = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), linked_to = c("2,4", 3,NA,NA,6,NA), stringsAsFactors = F)

# case linked_to
# 1          2,4
# 2            3
# 3         <NA>
# 4         <NA>
# 5            6
# 6         <NA>
```

In the example, case `1` is linked to cases `2` and `4`. Since case `2` is also linked to case `3`, it follows that case `1` is linked to cases `2`,`3` and `4`. I want to create a new column that specifies **all linked cases**:

```
# case linked_to all_linked
# 1          2,4    1,2,3,4
# 2            3    1,2,3,4
# 3         <NA>    1,2,3,4
# 4         <NA>    1,2,3,4
# 5            6        5,6
# 6         <NA>        5,6
```

I can do this using the `decompose.graph` function in igraph to fins isolated components, but the solution seems somewhat convoluted:

```
library(igraph)

# Transform to igraph format    

to <- sapply(df$linked_to, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x,",")) )

from <- rep(rownames(df), sapply(to, length) )

to <- unlist(to)

from <- from[!is.na(to)]
to <- to[!is.na(to)]

d <- data.frame(from,to)

gr <- graph.data.frame(d)

# Split into components
grs <- decompose.graph(gr)

comp <- sapply(grs, function(x) V(x)$name)

matches <-  sapply(df$case, function(case) {
  sapply(comp, function(comp) {
    case %in% comp
  })
})

matches <- as.data.frame(matches)

ind <- sapply(matches, which)

# Assign all members of the component they belong to to each vertex
df$all_linked <- sapply(ind, function(x) {
  paste(comp[[x]], collapse = ",")
})
```

Is there an easier and more efficient solution? **It can, but doesn't need to rely on network analysis tools**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit more efficient, using the `kpath.census` function in the `sna` package. (Alternative, you could use `distances` in `igraph` to the same effect.)

```
library(sna)
df <- data.frame(case = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
                 linked_to = c("2,4", 3,NA,NA,6,NA), 
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

net <- data.frame(case = c(1,1,2,3,4,5,6), 
                 linked_to = c(2, 4, 3,NA,NA,6,NA), 
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

g <- network(net[complete.cases(net),], directed = FALSE)

comemb <- kpath.census(g, maxlen = 10, mode = "digraph",  tabulate.by.vertex = TRUE, 
                       path.comembership = "sum")$path.comemb

comemb_names <- sapply(1:ncol(comemb), 
                       function(x) ifelse(comemb[x,] > 0 , 
                                          colnames(comemb)[x], 0))

comemb_names <- lapply(1:nrow(comemb_names), function(x) comemb_names[x,][comemb_names[x,] != "0"])

df$all_linked <- sapply(comemb_names, function(x) paste(x,collapse = ","))
```

Result:

```
> df
  case linked_to all_linked
1    1       2,4    1,2,3,4
2    2         3    1,2,3,4
3    3      <NA>    1,2,3,4
4    4      <NA>    1,2,3,4
5    5         6        5,6
6    6      <NA>        5,6
```

Comment: Thanks, but rows 1:4 should have the value `1,2,3,4` in the `all_linked` column. Case 4, for example, is linked to case 1, and case 1 is linked to case 2. Case 2, in turn, is linked to case 3. Therefore all links from/to case 4 are `1,2,3,4`.

Comment: Oops, `directed` should be set to `FALSE`. Now it produces the expected result.