# Crosslink values through different rows and columns with R

Tags: r, dataframe, matching

I have two columns of paired ID's as follows:

```
  id_a=c(12,15,68663,34,34,34,20,1001) 
  id_b<-c(67764,68663,68667,14,19,1001,20,2112)
  input=data.frame(id_a,id_b)
```

What I'm struggling to do is cross linking the paired values, so the expected output would look like this:

```
output=data.frame(id_linked_1=c(12,14,15,20),id_linked_2=c(67764,19,68663,20),id_linked_3=c(NA,34,68667,NA),id_linked_4=c(NA,1001,NA,NA),id_linked_5=c(NA,2112,NA,NA))
```

Any suggestions are very appreciated.

Comment: can you show the logic for the crosslinking

Comment: Every pair of Id refer to the same patient, but the same patient may have different pairs of Id. In the output provided row 2 shows a patient having 5 different id's.

Comment: The sequence of the crosslinked id's is not relevante.

Comment: @Axis but how can anyone help you if we don't know how you are selecting the ids to put in each column?

Comment: @Axis May be you are looking for an igraph solution?

Comment: ID 15 is linked  to iD 68663,  which is linked to ID  68667, so the 3 IDs are related.

Comment: @akrun I tried to do so, based on the post below, but id didnt work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42631880/transitive-relations-in-r-finding-all-linked-records-of-a-value

Answer (score 0):

Im posting here the solution https://stackoverflow.com/users/8245406/rui-barradas came up with.

```
library(igraph)

g <- graph_from_data_frame(input)
plot(g, vertex.size = 30, vertex.color = 'lightgrey', edge.arrow.width = 0.5)

v_num <- unique(match(input[[1]], names(V(g))))
path_list <- mapply(subcomponent, list(g), v_num)
names(path_list) <- v_num

path_list2 <- lapply(path_list, function(p){
  p <- unlist(p, recursive = FALSE)
  stringr::str_sort(unique(names(p)), numeric = TRUE)
})



final <- lapply(seq_along(path_list2), function(i){
  keep <- sapply(seq_along(path_list2)[-seq_len(i)], function(j){
    length(intersect(path_list2[[i]], path_list2[[j]])) == 0
  })
  if(all(keep)) path_list2[[i]] else NULL
})

final <- final[lengths(final) > 0]


sapply(final, paste, collapse = "//")
```